# Flow Balance in Chemical Engineering Process Flow Diagram

Tags: simulation

I am developing a chemical process simulation program that takes the user input of

1. Definitions of process units
2. A Process Flow Diagram (PFD) that depicts how the process units are connected and flow/mass stream directions;

The PFD may have recirculation loops. A simple example may look like this:

PFD:

```
Feed_Unit --> Chemical_Reactor --> Separator --> Product
                 ^                       |
                 |                       |
                 |<----(recirculation)---V (flow split)
                                         |
                                         L------> Waste_Material
```

The flow of Waste_Material is a function of the Chemical_Reactor and changes during simulation from one timestamp to the next.

I can balance the Feed, Waste_Material, and Product flows easily. What would be an efficient approach/algorithm to make sure the inner streams' flows are balanced too?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an 1000 level mass balance problem. It would be easier to just set up a bunch of systems of linear equations in matlab and use the rref() function. As long as it's not a transient problem.

Just write out all the balances and then plug em into matlab.